# Maximum Likelihood estimator for n in binomial with known p

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I have a question concerning the ML-estimation of the trials of a Binomial variable.
The setting is the following:

I have a random variable $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ unknown, $p\in (0,1)$ the known success probability and with density (w.r.t. to the counting measure) $p_n(x)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}=:L_x(n)$. The log-likehood function is therefore given by 
$$l_x(n)=\log L_x(N)=\log(n!)-\log(x!)-\log((n-x)!)+x\log(p)+(n-x)\log(1-p) .$$
Maximizing $l_x(n)$ w.r.t. to $n$ is equivalent to maximizing $\log(n!)-\log((n-x)!)+n\log(1-p)$ or $\frac{n!}{(n-x)!}(1-p)^n$.

My problem is that I don't know how to proceed from here. A person in this thread [Maximum likelihood estimate of $N$ (trials) in Binomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973823/maximum-likelihood-estimate-of-n-trials-in-binomial) suggested that a solution is given by $\hat{n}=X/p$. However, $X/p\notin \mathbb{N}$ for most $p$, so I suspect that this can't be the answer.

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181035/how-to-derive-the-likelihood-function-for-binomial-distribution-for-parameter-es) might help.

Comment: Thx, but this is deriving the MLE for p not n

Comment: Can you follow the procedure and adapt it so it fits your variable?

Comment: I don't see how the "standard MLE procedure" applies here. Taking the derivative of the log likelihood functino wrt to $n$ ends up with messy terms involving the derivative of $n!$

Comment: I think the result might turn messy, but do you know about the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)?

Comment: yes I do, but I don't think that this is the way to go with this problem. This problem was part of an old statistics exam, so there should be some "statistical way" to solving this

Comment: The maximum likelihood estimator requires you to maximize the likelihood function, no necessarily to do that with calculus. // And how about picking the integer part of $X/p?$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider  $\dfrac{{n+1 \choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n+1-x}}{{n \choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}} = \dfrac{(n+1)}{(n+1-x)}(1-p)$  which is less than $1$ when $n > \dfrac{x}{p}-1$, and so choosing $n+1$ in such a case would not give you a maximum likelihood estimate

Thus, given $x$ and $p$, your maximum likelihood estimate of $n$ is $\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{x}{p}\bigg\rfloor$ (rounding down)

unless $\dfrac{x}{p}$ is an integer in which case there are two with equal likelihood: $\dfrac{x}{p}-1$ and $\dfrac{x}{p}$

Comment: thx a lot, I got it now!

Comment: I didn't get it at all. Why should I consider this division term? Why would I want to choose n+1 ? Why should I be rounding down and not up?

Comment: @DavidRefaeli One way of finding whether one likelihood is greater than another is to divide one by the other and compare the result with $1$.  The actual division shows that any choice over $\frac x p$ does not give a maximum and also that any choice below  $\frac x p -1 $ also fails to  give a maximum.  That is why you round down

Comment: @Henry ok. Suppose I have 3 results of 4,5,6. And that p is 13/15. Rounding down will give me 17 if I take the total (from 17.3), or 5 if I take the average (from 5.7). Which is clearly wrong, as I have a result of 6, meaning that the minimal n is 6, or 18 for total. What am I missing?

Comment: @DavidRefaeli In the original question there was a single sample. There is an implicit indicator function in that that for the likelihood to be non-zero you need $n \ge x$ but that is not a problem as $\lfloor\frac{x}{p}\rfloor \ge x$.  In your example with three samples, the maximum likelihood estimator would be different  both because you start with $\prod\limits_i \frac{{n+1 \choose x_i}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{n+1-x_i}}{{n \choose x_i}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{n-x_i}}=\frac{(n+1)^3}{\prod(n+1-x_i)}(1-p)^3$  and because the estimator should explicitly be at least $\max(x_i)$

Comment: @Henry I think it's probably more the 2nd argument, as $\frac{(n+1)^3}{\prod (n+1-x_i)}(1-p)^3 < \frac{(n+1)^3}{(n+1-min(x_i))^3}(1-p)^3$ which is less than 1 .