# Estimating the Number of Trials in a Binomial Distribution?

Tags: probability

I am trying to learn more about the Binomial Probability Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

In most situations where I have encountered the Binomial Distribution, the situation was something like this:

- Suppose I flip a Coin 100 times (N) and observe 53 Heads (P) - what is the estimated probability of success?

In such a question, I am familiar on how Maximum Likelihood Estimation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) can be used to estimate the probability of success:

$$f(k;n,p) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
$$L(p) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i;n,p) = \prod_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{x_i}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{n-x_i}$$
$$\ln L(p) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln\left(\binom{n}{x_i}\right) + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\ln(p) + \sum_{i=1}^n (n-x_i)\ln(1-p)$$
$$\frac{d}{dp}\ln L(p) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{p} - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n-x_i}{1-p} = 0$$
$$\hat{p}_{MLE} = \frac{\sum x_i}{N}$$

In one of my classes, I recently learned that the Binomial Distribution can be presented in a different way.

For example:

Consider the following numbers:

```
16,17,25,22,19,20,18,17,18,25,16,24,13,17,21,21,24,19,21,18,22,21,17,16,22,21,15,24,22,17,19,23,20
,27,18,15,22,15,20,19,14,22,11,17,27,22,28,17,19,28,16,23,22,15,18,21,20,21,16,25,19,20,20,21,20,19
,24,21,18,18,21,29,30,19,22,15,18,22,24,19,21,16,15,22,16,20,20,19,19,21,20,18,16,23,22,27,26,21,17,21
```

Suppose these numbers were generated from some Binomial Distribution

**My Question:** How would we estimate (e.g. via MLE) the values of $N$ and $P$ in this Binomial Distribution?

In the earlier version of this problem, we were provided with $N$ and simply had to solve the MLE equations to solve for $P$.

But in the new version of this problem, we now have to solve for both $N$ and $P$ - but I am not quite sure how to do this.

**Can someone please help me understand how both $N$ and $P$ can be estimated in this situation?**

Thanks!

Comment: In this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution, you have some 'properties'. You already use property about 'expected Value', but you have some other properties.

Comment: @Lourrran: thank you so much for your reply! do you think you can please elaborate on this if you have time? thank you so much!